# Can we create more than one user account for an application that uses Tigris subversion?

Tags: svn, tigris

We have a java SWT based application that uses Tigris subversion (org.tigris.subversion). Currently we have one user name and password with admin privileges for everyone that uses the above mentioned application. We now desire to create another user name and password with reduced privileges. Does Tigris subversion support the creation of more than one user account? Any  help on this matter is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you say "Tigris Subversion" I assume that you use a very old and outdated version of Apache Subversion. Subversion is a project of Apache Software Foundation project for more than a decade. You have to upgrade your server to Subversion to version 1.10 or later.

> Does Tigris subversion support the creation of more than one user
>   account?

Yes, it does. Read the [documentation](https://www.visualsvn.com/support/svnbook/).